# Routes adding :id into an index resource with a concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

**routes.rb:**

```
# Allows a route to be queried by date
# eg: /any_route/dated/2016-01-01/2016-01-04
concern :datable do
  member do
    get 'dated/:start_date/(:end_date)', as: 'dated', constraints: {start_date: /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/, end_date: /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/}
  end
end

# I want to make the receipts "datable"
resources :receipts, only: :index, concerns: :datable, action: :index
```

It seems pretty straight forward, however, the route is being generated as this:

```
# The route I GET
dated_receipt GET /receipts/:id/dated/:start_date(/:end_date)(.:format)  receipts#index {:start_date=>/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/, :end_date=>/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/}
```

Notice the `:id` in the route? That shouldn't be there because I'm not querying a specific receipt, just the index.

I'm wanting to generate the following route (which is not currently happening):

```
# The route I WANT
dated_receipt GET /receipts/dated/:start_date(/:end_date)(.:format)  receipts#index {:start_date=>/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/, :end_date=>/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/}
```

Any idea why the `:id` is being added into the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is action on `collection`, not `member`:

```
collection do
  get 'dated/:start_date/(:end_date)', as: 'dated', constraints: {start_date: /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/, end_date: /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/}
end
```

You can read more about these routing aspects [in docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).